# Collapse CommandBar Visibility without modifying page layout

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a WP8.1 XAML application, and I'm having a problem with the application bar.

I have a couple of Flyouts that I display inside the app, with a code similar to this:

```
Flyout flyout = new Flyout();
flyout.Content = new SomeStuffUserControl();
flyout.Placement = FlyoutPlacementMode.Full;
flyout.Opened += (s, e) =>
{
       commandBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;                 
};
flyout.Closed += (s, e) =>
{
       commandBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
flyout.ShowAt(Window.Current.Content as FrameworkElement);
```

I collapse the CommandBar as I don't want it to waste space when the Flyout is displayed.
The problem is that sometimes when the Flyout is closed, I can see for a fraction of seconds that the whole page layout was "shifted" towards the bottom of the page (to cover the empty space were the CommandBar was), and if shifts back up as soon as the CommandBar reappears, and this looks quite ugly :/

If I'm not wrong, in WP8.0 I could set the AppBar opacity to 0.9 (for example), and then the page layout wouldn't consider it as "occupied space", but would cover the whole page behind the AppBar instead. This way, if I collapsed the AppBar visibility, the page layout wouldn't change.

Is there a way to do this in WP8.1?

Thanks! :)

Sergio

EDIT:
I found a solution and added that as an answer in case anyone else will find that useful :)

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I don't think it's possible for the app bar to take up no space when visible (AFAIK). Are any of your UI elements centered vertically on the page? This would cause the elements to re-center when the app bar is hidden. Try aligning your elements to the top of the page, or make the last row of your grid have height "*" so that it consumes the space taken up by the app bar when it is hidden. It's difficult to suggest a fix without knowing your exact XAML.

Comment: Did you try setting the opacity to "almost not transparent"? (.01 or .99)

Comment: Yup I tried that, I added it in my question as well. I thought it'd work like in WP8.0, but in WP8.1 it looks like the CommandBar keeps using effective space even though its opacity is not set at 1 :/ That'd have been an easy fix ahahahah

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution to the problem :)

This is a part of my XAML for the main page:

```
<!--LayoutRoot-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="mainRow" Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--Page content and stuff-->
</Grid>
```

I added that row definition and used that in my page constructor:

```
public Mypage()
{
    this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        mainRow.MaxHeight = mainRow.ActualHeight;
        mainRow.Height = new GridLength(mainRow.ActualHeight, GridUnitType.Pixel);             
    };
    this.InitializeComponent();
    //Stuff
}
```

Now when I set my BottomAppBar visibility to Collapsed, the page layout doesn't shift, without the need to set any vertical alignment to top (as I had a couple of things that used a bottom alignment).